# react.js uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to assign a variable's value based on another value in react.js. But it seems to be not working.

```
let user=localStorage.getItem('user');
let username="";
console.log(user);
if(user!==null || user!==undefined)
  username=JSON.parse(user).username;
```

console logs `null`, still it gives me:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null`

Comment: That is because if your entry is not available, you will get `null`. You will have to add a fail-safe. Check if user is of proper type and then process

Comment: @Rajesh maybe that's what i'm doing in `if(user!==null || user!==undefined)`

Comment: But the issue is that when you read from localStorage, its string. Its `"null"` instead of `null` and is processed to `null` using `JSON.parse`

Comment: `user !== null || user !== undefined` will always be true for any `user` value. Just make it `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
let user = localStorage.getItem('user') ;
let username = (user && JSON.parse(user).username) || "";
```

This will set username to an empty string if user is undefined or null.